# Get <Leader> value as <Space> and not ' '

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation, leader

Given that I defined `let mapleader="\<Space>"`, I would like to get in the **vimscript** the value of the `leader` as `<Space>` and not as `' '`. The latter may be obtained by using `get(g:,"mapleader","\\")`, but how to get the former? I'm searching for a formal solution to get `Tab` character as `<Tab>`, `escape` as `<Esc>`, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `substitute()`:

```
substitute(get(g:,"mapleader","\\"), ' ', '<Space>', '')
```

Since there is only one case where `get(g:,"mapleader","\\")` will return a single whitespace this should work.

Comment: I was hoping for some formal all-inclusive solution, e.g. to get `Tab` as `<Tab>`, etc. Is there something like this?

Comment: @igorepst Maybe someone can prove me wrong but I don't think you have a built-in way to do that

Comment: That's a pity. Let's wait for other answers before I accept yours

Comment: I tried to come up with something by abusing `nnoremap`, which prints its RHS in this form.  but it doesn't work for space and tab.. and just decided a look-up table is a lot simpler

Comment: Good, didn't think of that